# Bash inconsistent escaping of asterisk * in expect?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I've got 2 expect commands, however, I don't understand the expansion that's going on. (In context, I have a script that connects to a server, downloads and blanks all the log files in a specified directory.)

```
expect -c "
    set timeout 1
    spawn scp user@hostname:/logdir/\*.log .
    expect yes/no { send yes\n ; exp_continue }
    expect password: { send $pass\n }
    expect 100%
    sleep 1
    exit
";
```

In this command, expect displays the spawned command as `spawn scp user@hostname:/logdir/*.log .` Which means that the \ was removed.

```
expect -c "
    set timeout 1
    spawn ssh user@hostname {echo '' | tee /logdir/\*.log > /dev/null}
    expect yes/no { send yes\n ; exp_continue }
    expect password: { send $pass\n }
    expect eof
";
```

In this command, expect displays the spawned command as `spawn ssh user@hostname echo '' | tee /logdir/\*.log > /dev/null` Which means that the \ was *not* removed. Why is it different? (If I don't escape the asterisk, like `tee /logdir/*.log`, it does work. But I don't understand what is working differently from the above case?)

Comment: did the answer help solve your problem?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about this question till now. Yup, it helped me with my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how Tcl deals with backslashes.

```
[bash] # tclsh
% puts \*
*
% puts "\*"
*
% puts {\*}
\*
%
```

According to [Tcl doc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm):

> If a backslash (`\`) appears within a word then backslash substitution occurs.  **In all cases but those described below the backslash is dropped and the following character is treated as an ordinary character and included in the word.** The following table lists  the  backslash sequences that are handled specially, along with the value that replaces each sequence.
>
> [...]
>
> Backslash substitution is **not performed on words enclosed in braces, except for backslash-newline** as described above.

Comment: Globs for _remote_ files in scp (and sftp rcp rsync) don't need to be and usually can't be handled by the local shell, they are handled on the remote system by the peer process.

Comment: Yes you're right. Rolled back my answer and removed the part.